# perl regular expression matching between 2 or 3 characters and nothing else using the repetition curly braces

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to search for either 2 occurences or 3 of a certain character within a string but am not succeeding.

```
my $var = 'some text aaa some text';

if( $var =~ /a{2,3}/ )
{
    print 'good';
}
```

this is printing `good` when there is `aaaa`. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a word boundary, `\b`

```
my $var = 'some text aaa some text';

if ( $var =~ /\ba{2,3}\b/ ) {
    print 'good';
}
```